# Is Possible about IAP Subscription following case?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

My App service to user some contents about public domain movie, audio and so on...

for one month to download contents(no problem.) from any specific website URL.

Specific URL(has contents.) is updated every day by XML.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <audioCatalog xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:storage='https://blahblah.com/contents/'>
        <audio date="2012-07-16" category="...">
            <title>"..."</title>
            <description>"..."</description>
            <fileBase>"..."</fileBase>
        </audio>
        <audio date="2012-07-15" category="...">
            <title>"..."</title>
            <description>"..."</description>
            <fileBase>"..."</fileBase>
        </audio>
        <audio date="2012-07-14" category="...">
            <title>"..."</title>
            <description>"..."</description>
            <fileBase>"..."</fileBase>
        </audio>
                         .
                         .
                         .
     </audioCatalog>
```

user to click on UIButton can download new contents every day.

(https://blahblah.com/"..."<-- refer a fileBase)

```
imageURL: https://blahblah.com/"...png"
audioURL: https://blahblah.com/"...mp3" <-- user download contents if click on button
```

sample UI following.

[image]

In short, press a download button, is to give permission for one month.
 using a auto-renewable Subscription service(IAP). is this available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Wow you have changed your question significantly, this answer is no longer really applicable.

Yes, however there are two options; You could either offer a subscription service or you could use a simple IAP to buy the access for one month.

Comment: Subscriptions and Newsstand are two different things and can be used separately.

Comment: @FilipRadelic You are completely correct

Comment: could you please some more explain? for example, So if i use the ARS, I configure the server to verify subscribe system? Or simply through the process if iCloud Is that OK? because I simply the content upload to a specific URL(clouding service) by the user simply downloads the via XML. being subscribed verify to distinguish between using the iCloud. is no problem? or To determine whether a user has a valid subscription must have a server(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017731/any-early-experiences-with-auto-renewable-subscriptions-for-ios)? thanks.