# Auto-renewable subscriptions for iOS: How to get Server-side receipt validation?

Tags: php, ios, server, app-store, app-store-connect

I just finish to developp my app, create my Apple organization account, create all I need on the iTunes connect side, but my problem now, is to develop the **[server-side receipt validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1)** (because the [Validating Receipts Locally](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2) seems to have some **potential man in the middle security problems**).

```
...
    // Load the receipt from the app bundle.
    NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
    NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
    if (!receipt) { /* No local receipt -- handle the error. */ }

    /* ... Send the receipt data to your server ... */
...
```

I well-understanded the process of the validation as described on that picture:

[image]

My main problem is I am not a big expert about server's question, and if you have some examples of what I have to code for the receipt verification and what technologie I have to use (PHP, Angular, or else...).

(**First example:** On that [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017731/any-early-experiences-with-auto-renewable-subscriptions-for-ios), is the code on the server side is enough to accomplish that verification?)

(**Second example:** Is that process is good with the sending of the UDID and the receipt coded in Base64 to the server with a JSON, the server ask to the app store, the app store send ok, and the server send ok to the app. If it is the good process, I can do it easily. [Ticket 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581246/how-can-my-server-securely-authenticate-iphone-in-app-purchase/1794470?s=3%7C0.0000#1794470)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

I use my server to validate my the receipt like this:

https://github.com/aporat/store-receipt-validator

```
use ReceiptValidator\iTunes\Validator as iTunesValidator;

$validator = new iTunesValidator(iTunesValidator::ENDPOINT_PRODUCTION); // Or iTunesValidator::ENDPOINT_SANDBOX if sandbox testing

$receiptBase64Data = 'ewoJ
......
OVG8xTlNCRmRHTXZSMDFVSWpzS2ZRPT0iOwoJImVudmlyb25tZW50IiA9ICJTYW5kYm94IjsKCSJwb2QiID0gIjEwMCI7Cgkic2lnbmluZy1zdGF0dXMiID0gIjAiOwp9';

try {
  $response = $validator->setReceiptData($receiptBase64Data)->validate();
  // $sharedSecret = '1234...'; // Generated in iTunes Connect's In-App Purchase menu
  // $response = $validator->setSharedSecret($sharedSecret)->setReceiptData($receiptBase64Data)->validate(); // use setSharedSecret() if for recurring subscriptions
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'got error = ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}

if ($response->isValid()) {
  echo 'Receipt is valid.' . PHP_EOL;
  echo 'Receipt data = ' . print_r($response->getReceipt()) . PHP_EOL;
} else {
  echo 'Receipt is not valid.' . PHP_EOL;
  echo 'Receipt result code = ' . $response->getResultCode() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

And the WS on my server send me okay or not.

(For the local process on the iPad which is not advisable, you can find it here : [I'm getting 21004 as status value in reply from apple's sandbox server testing auto-renewable subscriptions in ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976453/im-getting-21004-as-status-value-in-reply-from-apples-sandbox-server-testing-a?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa))